# Count how many sub-activities were created based on an activity

Tags: dax

I have a dimension that stores workflows(cases, subcases). I would like to do a count of how many subcases are created for each case.

Workflow Dimension

```
Workflow
------------------------------
Case Number    WorkflowType
------------------------------ 
10             Case
20             Case
30             Case
20-1           Subcase
20-2           Subcase
20-3           Subcase
10-1           Subcase
```

The desire output I would like is, for every case count how many subcases were created.

```
Workflow
------------------------------------------------
Case Number    WorkflowType      CountOfSubcases
------------------------------------------------
10             Case               1
20             Case               3
30             Case               0
------------------------------------------------
Total                             4
```

I have a current dax measure that works, but the total at the bottom does not show when looking at multiple rows, only display when one case is selected.

```
Total Subcases = 
VAR CC = FIRSTNONBLANK ( Workflow[Case Number], 1 )
RETURN
COUNTX (
    FILTER (
        ALL( Workflow ),
        SUBSTITUTE ( Workflow[Case Number], RIGHT ( Workflow[Case Number], 2 
          ), "" )
            = CC
            && Workflow[WorkflowType] = "SubCase"
    ),
    Workflow[WorkflowID]
 )
```

If anybody could help me tweak my measure or present with a new measure, that would be great.

Note: I'm pointing my report to Analysis Services.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your measure as follows:

```
Total Subcases = 0 +
    COUNTX (
        FILTER (
            ALL( Workflow ),
            SUBSTITUTE ( Workflow[Case Number], RIGHT ( Workflow[Case Number], 2 ), "" )
                IN VALUES( Workflow[Case Number] )
            && Workflow[WorkflowType] = "SubCase"
        ),
        Workflow[WorkflowID]
    )
```

The `VALUES` function returns a list of all the values in the current filter context instead of just the one you were picking before.

---

Note: To make things easier to work with, I'd suggest splitting the `Case Number` column into two columns in the query editor stage. Then you don't have to work with all the string manipulation.

---

**Edit:** Note that `x IN <Table[column]>` is equivalent to the older [`CONTAINS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/contains-function-dax) syntax:

```
CONTAINS(Table, [column], x)
```

So if you can't use `IN` then try this formulation:

```
Total Subcases = 0 +
        COUNTX (
            FILTER (
                ALL( Workflow ),
                CONTAINS(
                    VALUES( Workflow[Case Number] ),
                    Workflow[Case Number],
                    SUBSTITUTE ( Workflow[Case Number],
                         RIGHT ( Workflow[Case Number], 2 ), "" )
                )
                && Workflow[WorkflowType] = "SubCase"
            ),
            Workflow[WorkflowID]
        )
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, 
thank you for you answer. I'm inputting your measure and is not working. I am using SSAS, I think that's why is barking.

Comment: What error is it throwing? You may need to use the older language for `IN`, i.e., the `CONTAINS` function.

Comment: The report measure 'Measure'[Total Subcases] has a syntax or semantic error at line 6, position 17, reported by Analysis Services:
The syntax for  'IN' is incorrect

Comment: Yup. `IN` is a newer functionality. Please see my edit.